# Nifi MergeRecord not working on avro flow files

Tags: avro, apache-nifi

[NiFi Flow to read json file infer avro schema merge content and store as parquet on hdfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBjGy.png)

Comment: See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please add a few more details about the flow and the processors' details. A quick check would be checking what's the `Min number of records` & `Attribute Strategy` properties set to?

Comment: Please click on NiFi Flow to read json file infer avro schema... above you can see my nifi flow pic..  Min number of records :1 & Attribute Strategy: Keep Only Common Attribute

Comment: And what is the `Merge Strategy` set to? Have you set anything for `Correlation Attribute Name`?

Comment: Merge Strategy set to Defragment I have not set anything for Correlation Attribute Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed Merge Strategy value Bin-Packing Algorithm to Defragment for MergeRecord processor and it started working.

Comment: Yes. The reason is `Defragment` strategy requires the flowfiles to have an identifier attributes `fragment.identifier` and `fragment.count`. NiFi docs page clarify many things in this regard: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/